# Pandas Error: Passing lists with missing labels

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe, syntax-error

## Sorry, I have solved this question by remodifying the source csv data with an extra column for exact_time. It is solved at the moment. Thank you for the answers Vishnudev and Anky

I have a data file "main_file.csv" which has data in the following format.

```
symbol,value
apple,340
ibm,194
```

When I try to use the below program to assimilate these values to its related csv files, I get an error which is shown at the end.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

main_list1 = ['apple', 'ibm']
df = pd.read_csv("main_file.csv")
df = df[df['symbol'].isin(main_list1)]

gb = df.groupby('symbol')
for name, group in gb:
    exact_time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    with open('{}.csv'.format(name), 'a') as f:
        group.to_csv(f, header=False, index=True, columns=[exact_time, "lastPrice"])
```

**Expected Output:**

**For the 'apple.csv':**

```
time,value
2020-04-08 22:00:11.863433,340
```

**For the 'ibm.csv':**

```
time,value
2020-04-08 22:00:11.863433,194
```

But the error I receive is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Testing\Trials.py", line 98, in <module>
    group.to_csv(f, header=False, index=True, columns=[exact_time, "lastPrice"])
  File "C:\Winpy\WPy64_368\python-3.6.8.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3202, in to_csv
    decimal=decimal,
  File "C:\Winpy\WPy64_368\python-3.6.8.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 115, in __init__
    self.obj = self.obj.loc[:, cols]
  File "C:\Winpy\WPy64_368\python-3.6.8.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1762, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "C:\Winpy\WPy64_368\python-3.6.8.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1289, in _getitem_tuple
    retval = getattr(retval, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "C:\Winpy\WPy64_368\python-3.6.8.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1954, in _getitem_axis
    return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Winpy\WPy64_368\python-3.6.8.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1595, in _getitem_iterable
    keyarr, indexer = self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis, raise_missing=False)
  File "C:\Winpy\WPy64_368\python-3.6.8.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1553, in _get_listlike_indexer
    keyarr, indexer, o._get_axis_number(axis), raise_missing=raise_missing
  File "C:\Winpy\WPy64_368\python-3.6.8.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1655, in _validate_read_indexer
    "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels "
KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'
```

Please help me fix the Passing list error.

Comment: what is the full traceback?

Comment: Your `to_csv` function call doesn't do what you expect it to. See docs.

Comment: Hi Chris, added full traceback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_csv` call in your code has incorrect columns argument. Also, there is no time column that is present.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

main_list1 = ['apple', 'ibm']
df = pd.read_csv("main_file.csv")
df = df.loc[df['symbol'].isin(main_list1)]

gb = df.groupby('symbol')
for name, group in gb:
    group = group.assign(time=dt.now()).drop(columns=['symbol'])
    group.to_csv(name + '.csv')
```

Comment: i think this should work, you can also do `group.assign(time=exact_time).drop(...).to_csv` in 1 go :)

Comment: Hello Vishnudev, thanks so much for your answer, and I need further help, as I receive the error here:C:\Winpy\WPy64_368\python-3.6.8.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:845: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: error: See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self.obj[key] = _infer_fill_value(value)
C:\Winpy\WPy64_368\python-3.6.8.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:966: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self.obj[item] = s

Comment: @Lokkii9 you can try `df = df[df['symbol'].isin(main_list1)].copy()` instead of `df = df[df['symbol'].isin(main_list1)]`

Comment: yes Anky, I did try the .copy() method by using it in my code and in 'Vishnudev's code... and it gave out same errors...I tried to modify everything, and even upgraded my python from 3.68 to 3.77.. still no change in the error...am sure its something on my end here..

Comment: Thanks Vishnudev.. I had found a workaround for the problem by rectifying the source data files.. but thank again